# Does the Warlock spell Hex require you to make an attack roll for the curse to land on its target?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, warlock

I understand that a target that is affected by Hex takes an additional 1d6 necrotic damage from attacks. Warlocks that use Eldritch Blast would deal 1d10 + 1d6 at level 1.

To cast Hex as your bonus action, does it just automatically land on the target, or do you have to roll your d20 against their AC to determine if it's successful?

Comment: Where does Hex come from? I can't find anything about it on the SRD. Is it a spell (and if so, which book?)

Comment: @Erik Pg 251 in the PHB

Comment: Interesting. Guess they didn't make that one openly available.

Comment: @Erik Relevant:  [Reddit post containing list of spells not in the SRD](https://www.reddit.com/r/UnearthedArcana/comments/4jevo5/a_list_of_spells_from_the_phb_that_arent_in_the/)

Comment: (I should clarify that it is only a list, not a circumvention of the limitations of the SRD)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is no spell attack associated with *hex*.  You cast it on the target and it affects the target until you stop concentrating or until the duration ends.

*Hex* doesn't cause any direct damage to the target; it adds an additional 1d6 to *other attacks* you make against the target.  If the target dies you can move *hex* to a new target.

Note that this is different than most spells that don't require a spell attack roll, in that it *always* succeeds.  For *hex*, there is no save to resist the spell or diminish the effect as there is for other non-spell attack spells which have negative effects for the target(s).

This spell is similar to the ranger spell *hunter's mark*, which has the same behavior.